# Keras - using activation function with a parameter

Tags: keras

How is it possible to use leaky ReLUs in the newest version of keras?
Function relu() accepts an optional parameter 'alpha', that is responsible for the negative slope, but I cannot figure out how to pass ths paramtere when constructing a layer.

This line is how I tried to do it,

```
model.add(Activation(relu(alpha=0.1))
```

but then I get the error

```
TypeError: relu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

How can I use a leaky ReLU, or any other activation function with some parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`relu` is a function and not a class and it takes the input to the activation function as the parameter `x`. The activation layer takes a function as the argument, so you could initialize it with a lambda function through input `x` for example:

```
model.add(Activation(lambda x: relu(x, alpha=0.1)))
```

Comment: Does not work for me...
`ValueError: Unknown activation function:<lambda>`

Comment: works for me, probably a typo in your code @RaphaelRoyer-Rivard

Comment: how would this work using the functional API? for example changing the alpha  parameter of the relu in `x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)`

Comment: Don't forget to wrap the lambda in a Lambda() function. Otherwise on the load_model function will break when trying to load a saved model from file.

`from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda; model.add(Activation(Lambda(lambda x: relu(x, alpha=0.1))))`

Comment: @leenremm Note that the serialization of `Lambda` layers is not portable between Python implementations, as noted in [the documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/lambda/) (perhaps not when this comment was originally written, however). I made a more comprehensive and [up-to-date answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69217717/13822943) including this information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from this source ([keras doc](https://keras.io/layers/advanced-activations/#leakyrelu)), and this [github question](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/117) , you use a linear activation then you put the leaky relu as another layer right after.

```
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU

model.add(Dense(512, 512, activation='linear')) # Add any layer, with the default of an identity/linear squashing function (no squashing)
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.001))   # add an advanced activation
```

does that help?

Comment: This does answer the question "How can I use a leaky ReLU?", but not the general question "or any other activation function with some parameter?".
In fact, it would be disappointing if one have to create a special layer for each activation function. The layer is Dense and the activation function is a part of the layer. Looking at https://keras.io/activations/ you can see that Keras offers what OP wants, the problem is that they aren't clear about **how to** use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a wrapper for parameterized activations functions. I've found this useful and more intuitive.

```
class activation_wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def _func(x):
            return self.func(x, *args, **kwargs)
        return _func
```

Of course I could have used a lambda expression in **call**.
Then

```
wrapped_relu = activation_wrapper(relu).
```

Then use it as you have above

```
model.add(Activation(wrapped_relu(alpha=0.1))
```

You can also use it as part of a layer

```
model.add(Dense(64, activation=wrapped_relu(alpha=0.1))
```

While this solution is a little more complicated than the one offered by @Thomas Jungblut, the wrapper class can be reused for any parameterized activation function. In fact, I used it whenever I have a family of activation functions that are parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

Keras defines separate activation layers for the most common use cases, including [`LeakyReLU`](https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/leaky_relu), [`ThresholdReLU`](https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/threshold_relu), [`ReLU`](https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/relu) (which is a generic version that supports all ReLU parameters), among others. See the full documentation here: https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers

Example usage with the [Sequential model](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model):

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(10))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy')
```

If the activation parameter you want to use is unavailable as a predefined class, you could use a plain `lambda` expression as suggested by @Thomas Jungblut:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
model.add(Activation(lambda x: tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.2)))
```

However, as noted by @leenremm in the comments, this fails when trying to save or load the model. As suggested you could use the [`Lambda` layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/lambda) as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Lambda
model.add(Activation(Lambda(lambda x: tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.2))))
```

However, the [`Lambda` documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/lambda#lambda-class) includes the following warning:

> WARNING: [`tf.keras.layers.Lambda`](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/lambda#lambda-class) layers have (de)serialization limitations!
>
> The main reason to subclass [`tf.keras.layers.Layer`](https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer#layer-class) instead of using a `Lambda` layer is saving and inspecting a Model. `Lambda` layers are saved by serializing the Python bytecode, which is fundamentally non-portable. They should only be loaded in the same environment where they were saved. Subclassed layers can be saved in a more portable way by overriding their `get_config` method. Models that rely on subclassed Layers are also often easier to visualize and reason about.

As such, the best method for activations not already provided by a layer is to subclass `tf.keras.layers.Layer` instead. This should not be confused with subclassing `object` and overriding `__call__` as done in @Anonymous Geometer's answer, which is the same as using a `lambda` without the `Lambda` layer.

Since my use case is covered by the provided layer classes, I'll leave it up to the reader to implement this method. I am making this answer a community wiki in the event anyone would like to provide an example below.