# Keras Functional API and activations

Tags: keras

I'm having problems when trying to use activations with Keras Functional API. My initial goal was to have choice between relu and leaky relu, so I came up with the following piece of code:

```
def activation(x, activation_type):
    if activation_type == 'leaky_relu':
        return activations.relu(x, alpha=0.3)
    else:
        return activations.get(activation_type)(x)


# building the model

inputs = keras.Input(input_shape, dtype='float32')
x = Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), padding='same')(inputs)
x = activation(x, 'relu')
```

but something like this gives error: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'`. I found out that it may indicate that my inputs and outputs in Model are not connected.

Is `keras.advanced_activations` the only way to achieve functionality like this in functional API?

EDIT: here's the version of activation function that worked:

```
    def activation(self, x):
        if self.activation_type == 'leaky_relu':
            act = lambda x: activations.relu(x, alpha=0.3)
        else:
            act = activations.get(self.activation_type)
        return layers.Activation(act)(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add an activation to your model by means of an activation **layer**. Currently, you are adding an object that is not a Keras `Layer`, which is causing your error. (In Keras, layer names always start with a capital). Try something like this (minimal example):

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
from keras import activations

def activation(x, activation_type):
    if activation_type == 'leaky_relu':
        return activations.relu(x, alpha=0.3)
    else:
        return activations.get(activation_type)(x)


# building the model
inputs = Input((5,), dtype='float32')
x = Dense(128)(inputs)
# Wrap inside an Activation layer
x = Activation(lambda x: activation(x, 'sigmoid'))(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It was helpful, but it wasn't all that was needed. I found the missing part of the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330431/6745559

Comment: Nice, thanks, I've edited my answer for future reference.