# Problem with keras functional api and leaky relu

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to use leaky relu. I tried using the mtd given by

[Keras Functional API and activations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948878/keras-functional-api-and-activations)

It doesn't work. I got the error:

TypeError: activation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'activation_type'

Also, should Activation be capital throughout or not?

I use it as:

```
def activation(x, activation_type):
    if activation_type == 'leaky_relu':
        return activations.relu(x, alpha=0.3)
    else:
        return activations.get(activation_type)(x)
...

input_data = layers.Input(shape=(3,))
...
hiddenOut = Dense(units=2)(input_data)
hiddenOut = activation(lambda hiddenOut: activation(hiddenOut, 'LeakyReLU'))(hiddenOut)
u_out = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='u')(hiddenOut)   
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something extra complicated, you can just

```
hiddenOut = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(hiddenOut)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import keras

def my_activation(x, activation_type):
    if activation_type == 'LeakyReLU':
        return keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.3)
    else:
        return keras.activations.get(activation_type)(x)

input_data = keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))
hiddenOut = keras.layers.Dense(units=2)(input_data)
hiddenOut = keras.layers.Activation(lambda hiddenOut: my_activation(hiddenOut, 'LeakyReLU'))(hiddenOut)
```

## Why

- `Activation` is a layer and `activations` is a set of available activation's.
- To emulate Leaky ReLu we have to change the slope of the  negative part. The slope is `0` for ReLu and this can be changed using the `alpha` parameter.
- What we are doing is a write a wrapper function called `my_activation` which will return a Leaky ReLu with negative slope of `0.3` if the parameter is `LeakyReLU` else it will return the normal activation.

Example:

```
input_data = keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))
a = keras.layers.Dense(units=2)(input_data)
a = keras.layers.Activation(lambda hiddenOut: my_activation(hiddenOut, 'LeakyReLU'))(a)
a = keras.layers.Activation(lambda hiddenOut: my_activation(hiddenOut, 'sigmoid'))(a)
a = keras.layers.Activation(lambda hiddenOut: my_activation(hiddenOut, 'tanh'))(a)
```

Comment: Ya, it worked! Thanks alot. Guess I may have missed out importing the libraries and mixing the capital letters etc.

Comment: Hey @quarkz, welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer works for you, you can mark it as answered, this helps other users and runs our reputation system.