# How can I assign a custom alpha for Keras relu function, for each node in a layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer, activation

I would like to add a node-specific variable to each Keras activation function. I would like each node to compute the activation value (output) with a different value (`alpha`).

This can be done **globally**, for example with the `alpha` parameter for the relu activation function ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330249/keras-using-activation-function-with-a-parameter)):

```
# Build Model
...
model.add(Dense(units=128))
model.add(Activation(lambda x: custom_activation(x, alpha=0.1)))
...
```

I can also write a custom activation function, but the `alpha` parameter is also **global**. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915482/how-do-you-create-a-custom-activation-function-with-keras))

```
# Custom activation function
def custom_activation(x, alpha=0.0):
    return (K.sigmoid(x + alpha))

# Build Model
...
model.add(Dense(units=128))
model.add(Activation(lambda x: custom_activation(x, alpha=0.1)))
...
```

Inside the custom function I only currently have access to the following variables:

```
(Pdb) locals()
{'x': <tf.Tensor 'dense/Identity:0' shape=(None, 128) dtype=float32>, 'alpha': 0.1}
```

I would like to use a custom activation function, but for `alpha` to be unique to each node in the network. For example, if there are 128 units in the layer, then I would like there also to be 128 values of alpha, one for each unit / node. I would then like the activation function to

How do I create an `alpha` value that is unique to each unit / node in a layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend to use lambda layer for that one, it is to hackish. I suggest you write your own layer as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Custom layer 
class CustomAct(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomAct, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.alpha = self.add_weight(name='alpha', 
                                      shape=[input_shape[1], ],
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(CustomAct, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        return tf.sigmoid(x+self.alpha)

    def get_alpha(self):
        return self.alpha        

inputs = np.random.random([16, 32]).astype(np.float32)

# Model 
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(inputs.shape[-1]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128))
model.add(CustomAct())

# Test
model.compile(loss="MSE")


alpha_after_initialization = model.layers[-1].get_alpha()
plt.plot(alpha_after_initialization.numpy())

x = np.random.random([18, 32])
y = np.random.random([18, 128])
for _ in range(20):
    model.fit(x, y)

out_after_20_steps = alpha_after_initialization = model.layers[-1].get_alpha()
plt.plot(alpha_after_initialization.numpy())

plt.show()
```

Of course, you should change all tf refernces to your keras ones.

Comment: I just assumed you want to make alpha trainable. If not, just set the arguemnt `trainable` to False and init it with your wanted values.

Comment: Fantastic! This answers 99% of what I am looking for. I would like to set alpha remotely (trainable = False). How would I write a set_alpha function?

Comment: Do you want to set alpha once at the beginning or update it live for every epoch?

Comment: Minor fix to your code: `inputs = np.random.random([16, 32]).astype(np.float32)` should be above `model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()`

Comment: Yes, this will work. However, if you really want to draw random samples, I would reccomend to do this directly in tensorflow?

Comment: Once-off update of alpha. The following seems to work: Inside the Class: `def set_alpha (self, val):` `self.alpha = val` `return True` After fit: `random_alpha_array = np.random.random([len(alpha_after_initialization.numpy())])` `random_alpha_array = tf.convert_to_tensor(random_alpha_array)` `model.layers[-1].set_alpha(random_alpha_array)` Would you recommend this?

Comment: Brilliant advice - much appreciated. Thanks!